# RangeError: Invalid time value

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm getting frequent errors when i start my server. Here is the error:

**RangeError: Invalid time value
      at Date.toISOString ()**

Here is the code:

```
var start = timestamp;
const expiryDate = (new Date(start)).toISOString().split('T')[0];
```

Comment: Works fine when I tried it out (by replacing timestamp with Date.now())

Comment: so what is `timestamp`?

Comment: you should debug your code by adding `console.log(timestamp);` to check what is the value when you have the error, and add it to the question..

Comment: Without seeing what `timestamp` is makes ❓relatively unproductive.

Answer (score 72):

This exception occurs when the Date object contains an invalid date.

```
new Date('undefined').toISOString()
```

In this example the Date object can be created without any problems, but the toISOString function throws an Error.

To fix your issue, you need to make sure that the timestamp variable contains a valid date string.

Comment: This happened to me because I was using a numeric string representing a timestamp instead of a number (like `'1606878000000'` instead of `1606878000000`, which can happen if you extract the value from a HTML element). I solved it using `parseInt()`.

Comment: Also occurs when putting an invalid (or undefined) date into i18n with `{{ $d(data.item.lastModified, 'short') }}`

Answer (score 4):

In my case `endDate` had a `null` value:

```
const [date, setDate] = useState([
  {
    startDate: new Date(),
    endDate: null,
    key: "selection",
  },
]);
```

Changing it to `new Date()` solved the issue:

```
const [date, setDate] = useState([
  {
    startDate: new Date(),
    endDate: new Date(),
    key: "selection",
  },
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had previously used [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) on an object `Task` with an attribute `duedate` of type Date.  Consequently `taskObj.duedate` became a string and did not work as a Date object in my code.

To fix the error, I converted the stringified date to Date type using `taskObj.duedate = new Date(taskObj.duedate);`

Answer (score 1):

This also occurs if you attempt to create a Date object from an invalidly formatted ISO string.  In my case, I had fiddled around with the month portion of some demo data to change it from `10` to `9`:

`"timestamp": "2023-9-29T08:54:40Z",`

This is invalid as the month portion of the date string is required to be two digits like so:

`"timestamp": "2023-09-29T08:54:40Z",`

Fixing this cleared up the error.

Answer (score 0):

for my case I have only converted it to JSON

const date_str = new Date(data?.invoice_date)?.toJSON()?.split("T")[0];
[image]

and i getting data from component into modal