# What is the data type of "date" returned by ReactJS Datepicker?

Tags: reactjs, datepicker

I have stored a date in database which is chosen from [ReactJS Datepicker](https://reactdatepicker.com/). First I chose date and then converted it into DD/MM/YYYY format using following code and with the help of [react-moment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-moment) which is shown below:

```
moment(this.state.dateOfBirth).format('DD/MM/YYYY')
```

Now on new page I want to show that date as selected but when I fetch that date from database its showing me error. It's throwing format error.

[image]

How can I set extracted date from DB to Selected attribute of datepicker?

Comment: Your date is not a valid date or not in a valid date format. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Invalid_date
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54462227/rangeerror-invalid-time-value

Valid date formats: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp

Comment: Please post your code as well

Comment: @NN796 As per your shared official MDN documents, if that format is not valid, then is that date from DatePicker is in String format?

Comment: please paste your code for more clarity. Thank you